# German and English Future tense differences

Tags: grammar, future

Is the German future tense similar to the English future tense? 
Or is it different? Can i use it the same way as the English future tense?

Comment: That is too vague a question to be properly answered here. Have you simply looked up the German future tense online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the different ways to talk about the future.
The first form of future would be to take a sentence in the present and just add a temporal adverb which describes a point in the future, as in:

> Morgen mache ich meine Hausaufgaben. | Tomorrow I do my homework.
>
> Morgen bin ich am Hausaufgaben machen | Tomorrow I am doing my homework

The next step is the Futur I, which is formed with "werden + Infinitiv"

> Morgen werde ich meine Hausaufgaben machen. | Tomorrow I will do my homework.
>
> Morgen werde ich am Hausaufgaben machen sein. | Tomorrow I will be doing my homework.

And finally, there is Futur II, which is formed with "werden + Perfekt"

> Morgen Abend werde ich meine Hausaufgaben gemacht haben. | Tomorrow evening I will have done my homework.
>
> Morgen Abend werde ich am Hausaufgaben machen gewesen sein. | Tomorrow evening I will have been doing my homework.

So it seems that they are pretty similar and it is probably save to say, that you can use them equally.

Comment: An edit is necessary to fix the disinformation here. First off, German does have the gerund, its just more rare. The progressive does exist as well, using the am+infinitive construction.

Comment: You're right, I took another look and edited my answer. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Einige deiner deutschen Beispiele sind nicht standardsprachlich (google mal [rheinische Verlaufsform](https://www.google.de/search?q=rheinische+verlaufsform)), und während im Deutschen das Präsens immer eine futurische Bedeutung haben kann ("Morgen mache ich meine Hausaufgaben"), ist das im Englischen nur dann möglich, wenn von einem feststehenden Ereignis die Rede ist ("The train leaves at eight."), aber nicht, wenn eine Absicht ausgedrückt ("I'm going to do my homework tomorrow.") oder ein spontaner Entschluss gefasst wird ("I'll do my homework tomorrow.").

Comment: Siehe auch http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/grammar/futur_gegenueberstellung.htm